# onmouseover() event and onclick() event handling for same html button

Tags: html, vb.net, vbscript, event-handling, onmouseover

I want to get a small window saying "Hello world" on mouseover action over a button named as **Log**. Now I have a button action **LogOpen()** defined which opens a log file **onclick** of the Log button.

How can I perform two actions on the Log button so that **onmouseover**  should display a prompt and **onclick** of the same Log button should fetch  the log file as it is doing currently?

Any example code snippets will be helpful how to tackle this on mouseover() event along with the OnClick() for my below code.

**LogOpen() function:-**

```
<script type="text/Vbscript">
Option Explicit
Dim File
File = "C:\\test.txt"
'***********************************************************
Sub LoadMyFile()
    myDiv.innerHTML = LoadFile(File)
End Sub
'***********************************************************
Function LogOpen(File)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fso,F,ReadMe,Tab,i,paragraphe
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set F = fso.OpenTextFile(File,1)
    LoadFile = Err.Number
    If Err.Number <> 0  Then
        MsgBox Err.Description,16," Error"
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReadMe = F.ReadAll
    Tab = split(ReadMe,vbcrlf)
    For i = lbound(Tab) to ubound(Tab)
        paragraphe=paragraphe & Tab(i) & "<br>"
    Next
    LoadFile = paragraphe
End Function </script>
```

**HTML Log button**

```
<input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="Log" onclick="LogOpen()">
```

**Alert message not displaying onmouseover()**

```
<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById("Start").onmouseover = function() {
  alert("hi")
}
</script>
```

**JS location**

```
<body text="black">
<table>
  <p>&nbsp;Log</p>

       <input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="Open Dctm" onclick="LogOpen()">

  </tr><br/>
</table>
<Div id="myDiv"></Div>
<td height="37" width="495" align="center">
<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById("Start").onmouseover = function() {
  alert("hi")
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want any thing fancy just add title attribute to your input button.

```
<input type="button" name="Log" id="Start" value="Log" onclick="LogOpen()" title="hello world">
```

here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgD65/) for above code

And if you want to give some fancy popup on hover you can use http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style for this.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I want a popup or a small window onmouseover of the button, can you show some examples to me so that I can get some clarity about the suggested approach?

Comment: Sorry i posted the answer in hurry.

Comment: @Sandeeproop the jquery link that you have provided is not working. I checked the JFiddle link but this is not what I was looking for. I wanted the onmouseover defined in such a way that both onClick() and onmouseOver() functionality stays for the same log button. I want onmouseover() in form of a function so that I can write some more logic inside the onmouseover() function and certainly not as a tooltip title. I want specifically onmouseover event

Comment: I tried the one you suggested but it is not displaying alert message on hover and have pasted the code section. Is there anything wrong in the code which I have pasted above under the title "Alert message not displaying onmouseover()"? It is not responding to hover action, strange indeed.

Comment: Where are you adding you js code.
please write your js at the end of <body> tag

Comment: In my original post I just pasted my current JS location, it is inside the body. Is there something wrong in that, please take a look under heading JS location.